# Stop executing code after while loop ( not break )

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have code which checks if a user already present in a Database. After the while Loop I check the Mojang API if the MC Player is in their Database but if the user is already present in my Database I don't want to check the Mojang API. Something like break with the loops.

Here is the Code:

```
// Checken ob schon ein Benutzer mit der Mail / Username vorhanden ist
    conn.connect(function(err) {
      var sql = "SELECT email, mc_name FROM users"
      conn.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        i = 0
        while(i < result.length) {
          mailDB = result[i].email
          mc_nameDB = result[i].mc_name

          if(mailDB == email || mc_nameDB == email) {
            res.status(403).send("USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED")
            // Here it should stop (not just the loop with break but also the whole script)
            break
          } else {

          }
          i++
        }
      })
    })

    axios.post('https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate', {
          "agent": {
            "name": "Minecraft",
            "version": 1
          },
          "username": email,
          "password": pw,
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data.selectedProfile.name)
      res.status(200).send("USER_DATA_CORRECT")

      uname = response.data.selectedProfile.name
      uuid = response.data.selectedProfile.id

      // Password hashen
      bcrypt.hash(pw, 2, function(err, hash) {
        conn.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          var sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, mc_name, mc_uuid) VALUES ('" + email + "', '" + hash + "', '" + uname + "', '" + uuid + "')";
          conn.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
          });
        });
      });

      return
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
      if(error.response.status == 403) {
          res.status(403).send("USER_DATA_INCORRECT")
          return
      } else {
          res.send("ERROR_500")
          res.status(500)
          return
      }
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How about replacing `break` with `return`?

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. It also executes the console.log

Comment: Of course, because the last line is possibly executed before the callback that you are passing to `conn.connect`. If this is your entire script, then simply remove anything after your call to `conn.connect`.

Comment: Oh ok but I thought return just stops a function.

Comment: It does, but the function here is a callback, which is called asynchronously relatively to the rest of your script. You do understand what a callback is, right?

Comment: I have updated the post. There is a Post to the Mojang API after this. So the problem is not stopping the SQL query but to stop the whole script.

Comment: Please don't create inserts like that, you have to sanitize the user input before getting to the database or you'll be exposing your app to SQL injection

Comment: I just started with this project. I will do this in a later step :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Put everything after the call to `conn.connect` inside a function.
2. Call that function right before the `break` in `conn.connect`.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem but something like this also was my first intention but isn't there a simpler way to stop the script.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `return` where you have `break`.

Comment: Return doesn't solve the problem. It also executes the console.log